# Laravel eloquent where and orWhere issue fetching correct data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have the following query builder which generates this query:

My problem lies within the where condition in the sale and stock options, when using the min and max price filtering. My URL looks like this:

```
category/men-clothes?sale=no_sale&min_price=10&max_price=10000&per_page=8
```

sale=no_sale, means the query performs the where 'sale_price', '=', 0, hence this in my SQL query:

```
and `sale_price` = ? order by `id` desc
```

Yet, it still fetches products whose sale_price is bigger than 0, but when I switch to on_sale, only products with sale_price bigger than 0 are fetched. So the problem is only when selecting products that have no active sale.
So goes for the on_stock and no_stock where, it just doesn't fetch the right products. I know the builder is quite big, but I haven't been able to figure why it is not working properly. It only works properly after I remove the min_price and max_price filtering completely SO it has to be somewhere in the where and orWhere in the price filtering that causes those issues.

.

```
select * from `products` where exists (select * from `categories` inner join `product_categories` on `categories`.`id` = `product_categories`.`category_id` where `products`.`id` = `product_categories`.`product_id` and `id` = ?) and (`has_variants` = ? and `price` >= ?) or (`has_variants` = ? and `min_price` != ? and `min_price` >= ?) and (`has_variants` = ? and `price` <= ?) or (`has_variants` = ? and `max_price` != ? and `max_price` <= ?) and `sale_price` = ? order by `id` desc
```

.

```
$products = Product::whereHas('categories', function ($query) use ($category) {
            $query->where('id', '=', $category->id);
        })->when(count($brand_list) > 0, function ($query) use ($brand_list) {
            $query->whereHas('brand', function ($query) use ($brand_list) {
                $query->whereIn('slug', $brand_list);
            });
        })->when($minPrice, function ($query) use ($data) {
            $query->where([
                    ['has_variants', '=', 0],
                    ['price', '>=', $data['active_filters']['min_price']],
                ])
                ->orWhere([
                    ['has_variants', '=', 1],
                    ['min_price', '!=', 0],
                    ['min_price', '>=', $data['active_filters']['min_price']],
                ]);
        })->when($maxPrice, function ($query) use ($data) {
            $query->where([
                ['has_variants', '=', 0],
                ['price', '<=', $data['active_filters']['max_price']],
            ])
                ->orWhere([
                    ['has_variants', '=', 1],
                    ['max_price', '!=', 0],
                    ['max_price', '<=', $data['active_filters']['max_price']],
                ]);
        })->when($orderPrice, function ($query) use ($orderPrice) {
            $query->orderBy('price', $orderPrice);
        })->when(!$orderPrice, function ($query) {
            $query->orderBy('id', 'desc');
        })->when($stockOrder, function ($query) use ($stockOrder) {
            if($stockOrder == 'in_stock') {
                $query->where('quantity', '>', 0);
            } else if($stockOrder == 'no_stock') {
                $query->where('quantity', '=', 0);
            }
        })->when($saleOrder, function ($query) use ($saleOrder) {
            if($saleOrder == 'on_sale') {
                $now = time();
                $query->where([
                    ['sale_price', '>', 0],
                    ['sale_start', '<', $now],
                    ['sale_end', '>', $now],
                ])->orWhere([
                    ['sale_price', '>', 0],
                    ['sale_start', '=', 0],
                    ['sale_end', '=', 0],
                ]);
            } else if($saleOrder == 'no_sale') {
                $query->where('sale_price', '=', 0);
            }
        })->when($featuredOrder, function ($query) use ($featuredOrder) {
            if($featuredOrder == 'featured') {
                $query->where('featured', '=', 1);
            } else if($featuredOrder == 'not_featured') {
                $query->where('featured', '=', 0);
            }
        })->when(count($activeColors) > 0, function ($query) use ($activeColors) {
            $query->whereHas('colors', function ($query) use ($activeColors) {
                $query->whereIn('value', $activeColors);
            });
        })->when(count($activeSizes) > 0, function ($query) use ($activeSizes) {
            $query->whereHas('sizes', function ($query) use ($activeSizes) {
                $query->whereIn('value', $activeSizes);
            });
        })->with(['colors', 'sizes', 'reviewsCount'])->get();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem here are `orWhere`. When you use orWhere you should probably always wrap construction with additional closure. Let's look at:

```
->when($minPrice, function ($query) use ($data) {
            $query->where([
                    ['has_variants', '=', 0],
                    ['price', '>=', $data['active_filters']['min_price']],
                ])
                ->orWhere([
                    ['has_variants', '=', 1],
                    ['min_price', '!=', 0],
                    ['min_price', '>=', $data['active_filters']['min_price']],
                ]);
        })
```

This part should probably look like this:

```
->when($minPrice, function ($query) use ($data) {
      $query->where(function($query) use ($data) {
            $query->where([
                    ['has_variants', '=', 0],
                    ['price', '>=', $data['active_filters']['min_price']],
                ])
                ->orWhere([
                    ['has_variants', '=', 1],
                    ['min_price', '!=', 0],
                    ['min_price', '>=', $data['active_filters']['min_price']],
                ]);
          });
        })
```

As you see above the whole `where .. orWhere` was wrapped into additional closure.

The reason for this is quite obvious. If you don't have additional closure you can produce query like this

```
WHERE A and B or C and D or E
```

and usually it should be like this:

```
WHERE A and (B or C) and (D or E)
```

so when you use closures they will add extra parenthesis to query to make it work.

The same way you should obviously wrap all the others `where ... orWhere` constructions to make it work as you expect

Comment: Yep, thanks. I just had to wrap all my where clauses with an extra where to enclose them. Thank you so much! It works like a charm now.